# Customize interactive notification buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

How can I customize the buttons which show up when a notification is presented as an alert? Let me clarify what I mean: After I have created some interactive notification actions and put them in a category for my local notifications to use, everything works great. However, when a notification is presented as an alert view, I get two buttons only: **Close** and **Options**. Is there a way to customize these buttons? Similar to how the reminders app does it, you get these two buttons instead of **Close** and **Options**.

[image]

***And this is what I get:***

[image]

Can someone please clarify what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise button titles by changing their values, here is an example:

`UIAlertView* alert;
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:@"Reminder" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Mark as Completed" otherButtonTitles: @'Later'];
[alert show];
[alert release];`

Here is an example with push notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:userInfo[@"Reminder"][@"alert"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Mark as Completed" otherButtonTitles:@"Later"];
[alertView show];
}
else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is an alert view, not  a notification

Comment: This is actually what you asked for :D.

Comment: No, I said when a notification is presented as an alert view? That is, not on the lockscreen or as a banner

Comment: **How can I customize the buttons which show up when a notification is presented as an alert?**

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to change this tittles, it will be only close and options.

Reminders app has different scenario, it comes with iOS version only. so it is basically coded that way.

But in app development, we can change it.